# sqlalchemy exists() - how to avoid extra From

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

exists() containing another exists() results in extra From clause.

```
model.session.query(Table1.id).\
    filter(~ exists().\
         where(Table2.table1_id==Table1.id).\
         where(~ exists().\
                 where(Table3.contract_id==Table2.contract_id).\
                 where(Table3.session_id==Table1.session_id))
         )
```

this is generating:

```
SELECT table1.id AS table1_id FROM table1
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2
            WHERE table2.table1_id = table1.id
            AND NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table3, table1
                     WHERE table3.contract_id = table2.contract_id
                     AND table3.session_id = table1.session_id))))
```

Here, "FROM table1" in the last "exists" is not required because table1 is already in the topmost query. How can I force sqlalchemy not to add this extra "FROM table1"?

What I really want is:

```
SELECT table1.id AS table1_id FROM table1
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2
          WHERE table2.table1_id = table1.id
          AND NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table3
                   WHERE table3.contract_id = table2.contract_id
                   AND table3.session_id = table1.session_id))))
```

I wonder how to achieve that.
Can somebody help me please?
Using SQLAlchemy 0.7.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
q = (session.query(Table1.id)
     .filter(~exists(
         select([Table2.id])
         .where(Table2.table1_id == Table1.id)
         .where(~exists(
             # changing exists to be implicit enables the 'important' below
             select([Table3.id])
             .where(Table3.contract_id == Table2.contract_id)
             .where(Table3.session_id == Table1.session_id)
             # this is important
             .correlate(Table1)
             .correlate(Table2)
             ))
     )))
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working.  Except that I had to replace correlate(Table1) into correlate(Table1.table) since Table1 was a class.

Comment: Strange that you *had* to, as correlate accepts mapped classes as arguments as well. But glad it worked as expected.